# Solve using Laplace Transform $2y''+5y'+2y=e^{-2t}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

My teacher gave this question to solve using Laplace Transform

\begin{cases}
2y''+5y'+2y={e^{-2t}}\\
y(0)=1, y'(0)=1
\end{cases}

Taking Laplace transform on both sides we get: 
$$L\{2y''(t)+5y'(t)+2y(t)\}=L\{e^{-2t}\}$$
Using laplace transform in ODE 
$$L\{y'(t)\}=sL\{y(t)\}-y(0)$$
and 
$$L\{y''(t)\}=s^{2}L\{y(t)\}-sy(0)-y'(0)$$
I got
$$L\{y(t)\}=\frac{7}{\left(2s^2+5s+2\right)^{\:}}+\frac{2s}{\left(2s^2+5s+2\right)^{\:}}+\frac{1}{\left(s+2\right)\left(2s^2+5s+2\right)^{\:}}$$

I can easily solve the inverselaplace of the equation and get the solution for y.
But my answer is not matching with the one given by the teacher.
So could anyone tell me had I made any mistake finding the value of L{y}?

The final answer I got is $$ -\frac{e^{-2t}t}{3}+\frac{20}{9}e^{-\frac{t}{2}}-\frac{11}{9}e^{-2t}$$
PLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD THE SOLUTION.
EDIT: I am extremely sorry, the initial values should be $y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show how you got this expression for $L$, & the expression your teacher gave as correct?

Comment: @J.G. In just did

Comment: @Moo I just provided how I end up with the answer.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make clear how you jumped from those facts about Laplace transforms to this result. Surely those facts instead imply$$Ly=\frac{Le^{-2t}}{2s^2+5s+2}.$$(BTW, I recommend writing the identities in the same variables your problem uses, e.g. $Ly^\prime(t)=sLy(t)-y(0)$.)